# Why is my scraper returning an empty list while trying to scrape from this https://www.airtel.in/myplan-infinity/?

Tags: python

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.airtel.in/recharge-online?icid=header_new"

source = requests.get(url)

Soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")
info = Soup.find_all(class_="right-content")
print(info)
```

Comment: There could be many reasons, try printing source.text to console or writing it into a file and opening into a browser.

Comment: The data is loaded dynamically. Try to retrieve the page with Selenium before parsing with bs4

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no 'right-content' class. Yes, you can see it when you use 'inspect' tool in your browser, but your browser can run and indeed run all js dynamic code in the loaded page and you see it AFTER js work. But when you use request, request gives you code without js work. 
You can try `print(source.text)` to get html in which you try to find 'right-content' class and then you see there is nothing but unworked js.